# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6756.parquet

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

While writing the data frame to s3 in parquet format i got the below error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o6756.parquet.
```

but couldn't find any solution to rectify this issue.

Comment: Could add the following lines error??

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had an error in **udf** while removing the element from the list it was going out of range because i was removing the element by index So, to fix that issue i had to make a **deepcopy** of the list and then started removing the elements.